# [Vue warn]: Property "formatPrice" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance at <App>

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js, frontend, razor-pages

I'm following a series of .NetCore  tutorials and Vue.js is being used in the project of it and I don't know much about it.. here is the code:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data: {
        price: 0
    },
    computed: {
        formatPrice: function () {
            return "$ " + this.price;
    }
});
app.mount('#app');
```

and here is the related razor page :

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
}

<div id="app">
    <input type="number" v-model="price"/>
    <p>
        {{price}}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{formatPrice}}
    </p>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/js/Admin/main.js"></script>
}
```

note that I've put the cdn for Vue at the _layout.cshtml in pages/shared folder, otherwise it won't work.
When I run the program I get this error at console :

[Vue warn]: Property "formatPrice" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance at

How can I figure this out?

Comment: What is Vue.js version? also, insure that id="app" is not used in elsewhere. and also Ensure that the CDN for Vue.js is loaded before your script. Your <script src="~/js/Admin/main.js"></script> should come after Vue.js is loaded.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good tutorial if it's using Vue and not teaching you how Vue works.  [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html) and other good Vue specific tutorials are out there that you might want to look into.